# 404 error for a file that is absolutely there

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 error for a file that is absolutely there.

It's at location `domain.com/video/videoname.mp4`. When I try to play it using Flash, it says video not found or access denied.

It keeps giving not found errors.

When I navigate to `domain.com/video/`, videoname.mp4 appears very clearly there. However, when I click it, it gives a 404 error.

Would this be a permissions issue?

It's a Windows server, which I'm less useful. There's also an IIS install, but it isn't used in the actual administration of this particular site.

My guess is a server setting or a permissions setting, but I'm trying to do a sanity check here.

Comment: Is it because of security/crossdomain issues?

Comment: no, all on the same domain.

Comment: Do you have anything like [URLScan](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan) installed?  I know we've have problems with clients who have it installed and it blocking certain file types (especially .exe)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the IIS server to run under a specific account one that doesn't have access issues.  I would just make sure you create an application account to do this and don't put it on a user account.  I know that there are IUSR accounts that are the default accounts that are used by IIS these default accounts might have the permission issues.

Another possibility is that the MIME type for the video is not setup properly.  You could put a basic html file in this directory to test to see if the extension MIME mapping might be a problem.